# How to write a global dictionary inside a function?

Tags: python, global-variables

I have come across something in Python that I don't understand.
I wrote some code that plays legal chess moves. The position of the pieces is remembered in a dictionary that I've called `board`, with an integer representing the square as a key, and the name of a piece as its value.

These values obviously change as the game progresses. I wanted to add a reset button, and originally thought I could just create a backup (e.g. `backup = board`), and then a function that would say `board = backup`. I've found this works *but only* if I add a second statement of the dictionary.

Here is some code that might make it clearer:

```
board = {11: 'white rook', 12: 'white knight', 13: 'white bishop'}
backup = board
# if I comment out this next line the code doesn't work 
board = {11: 'white rook', 12: 'white knight', 13: 'white bishop'}

def move_knight():
    board[12] = 'empty'  # as the knight moves away
    
def reset():
    global board
    board = backup
    print("board in reset function =", board)

move_knight()
print("board after knight's move =", board)
reset()
print("board after reset =", board)
```

In a sense I have solved my problem but would like to understand why.

Comment: `backup = board` **does not create a copy**. You now have two variables referencing the same list object

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Andrew, have you had a look at the answer below and did you find it helpful? Please check and upvote/accept if it answers your question. Thanks!

Comment: @tbjorch yes very useful, thank you. The article cited above by juanpa.arrivillaga is also very helpful

Answer (score 1):

### Explaining problem

You are just creating a new list and change the reference of 'board' variable to a new list.

```py
first = [1, 2, 3]  # Creating a list and variable 'first' refers to the list
second = first     # Creating variable 'second' and refer to the same list as first
first = [3, 4, 5]  # Create a new list and let variable 'first' refer to the new list
```

if you try this you would see that the variables are pointing on the same list:

```py
first = [1, 2, 3]
second = first
print(first, second) # outputs [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
first[0] = 5 # <--- updating via variable 'first'
print(first, second) # outputs [5, 2, 3] [5, 2, 3]
```

### How to create a copy

If you use the copy method you will see that you are indeed creating a copy of the list into the new variable and not only just referring to the same list.

```py
first = [1, 2, 3]
second = first.copy()
print(first, second) # outputs [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
first[0] = 5
print(first, second) # outputs [5, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```